# Difference between %assign and %define

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, preprocessor

What is the difference between `%assign` and `%define` in NASM assembly x86? Because for me it looks like they are the same thing, well, not really. Is `%assign` just a `%define` for which you can change later in the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are not part of x86 assembly, they’re specific to nasm. They’re similar but not quite: `%assign` defines a numeric constant and it can be redefined. It cannot take arguments.`%define` defines a numeric or string valued macro, it can take arguments, and can also be redefined.

More information in the [documentation](https://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc4.html)

Comment: `%define` is always a text substitution, isn't it?  So the ability to redefine it doesn't let you do stuff like `%define i  i+1` in a `%rep`.

Comment: @PeterCordes: `%assign` also works if you have some arithmetic involving `$` or `$$`, which would be evaluated later than the directive, at use of the macro, if used with `%define`.

Comment: @ecm: Someone should probably write up a more detailed answer to this, since [Is there a point in using %assign macro if %define macro has more functionality (NASM)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71551054) has now been updated to clarify that this Q&A wasn't sufficiently helpful.  I may get around to that, but if you'd like to cook up an answer with some useful examples that'd be great.

Comment: @PeterCordes: If you end up writing it, also consider `%xdefine`. Your `i + 1` example could actually use `%xdefine` too, it would just need way more space and time for NASM to keep track of the expansion. (Eg in a `%rep` loop of a thousand iterations and starting at `%define i 0` the define would end up using thousands of bytes.)